# Delphi Listview onInsert Problem

Tags: delphi, listview

I am using 2 listviews and am copying items from one to another (using the code below) however when the onInsert event of the destination Listview is triggered the Item value passed is always nil rather than the newly moved list item, could someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

```
Source.Items.BeginUpdate;
Destination.Items.BeginUpdate;
for i := Source.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
 if Source.Items[i].Selected then
   begin
    Destination.Items.Add.Assign(source.Items[i]);
    Source.Items[i].Delete;
  end;
Source.Items.EndUpdate;
Destination.Items.EndUpdate;
```

Thanks

Colin

Comment: You are not *copying* items, you are *moving* them.

Comment: I thought I knew the answer, but I was wrong. My spontaneous reaction is that the VCL/common control behaves strangely...

Comment: +1 because this is a mystery!

Comment: @Adreas yes sorry I meant move.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot duplicate `OnInsert` being called with a `nil` Item. Hence I presume you mean, when `OnInsert` is called the Item parameter does not have the properties (caption, data, image index etc..) of the source item. The reason is, when 'OnInsert' is called, the assignment is not yet carried out.

This line

```
Destination.Items.Add.Assign(source.Items[i]);
```

is analogous to

```
var
  Item: TListItem;
 ...
  Item := Destination.Items.Add;  // <- OnInsert is called here
  Item.Assign(source.Items[i]);
```

Comment: It 'looks' like `nil` if Debug DCUs is not turned on.

Comment: In 2009 the object inspector refuses to show any details about the `Item` parameter unless Debug DCUs are on. Of course, it *isn't* `nil`, but it kind of looks like it. [No Debug DCUs](http://privat.rejbrand.se/noitem.png) vs [Debug DCUs](http://privat.rejbrand.se/isitem.png)

Comment: @Andreas - I understand now, same here... As a side note, I'm guessing I'm not even supposed to put a breakpoint in 'OnInsert', there's about a %50 percent chance that the debugger crashes with a brand new project with a single breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `Caption` (or any other interesting property) of the newly created `TListItem` hasn't been set yet. It is somewhat of a mystery that the VCL offers this `Item` parameter, because I have tried all imaginable ways of adding a new list item, but non of them result in any useful `Item` parameter. The event was always called *before* the properties were set. Maybe you are only supposed to *set* the properties of this parameter, not *read* them.

I think you have to rethink the design. A workaround that might or might not work for you is to use the `OnChange` event instead. Of course, this will fire not only when the item is first inserted, but anytime the item is changed.

```
procedure TForm1.DestinationChange(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Change: TItemChange);
begin
  ShowMessage(Item.Caption);
end;
```

It might be a bit of a 'hack', but if you really want to mimic the scenario you would have had if the original approach had worked (that is, if the `Item` parameter would have been fully initialized), you could do something like

```
var
  tmpItem: TListItem = nil; // preferably this should
                            // be a private member of the form class instead

procedure TForm1.DestinationChange(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Change: TItemChange);
begin
  if Assigned(Item) and (Item = tmpItem) then
  begin
    // Here you got the real item you just added
    ShowMessage(Item.Caption);
    tmpItem := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DestinationInsert(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  tmpItem := Item;
end;
```

But if I were you, I'd definitely redesign. Hacks aren't good. (At least I wouldn't trust this hack.) After all, it is *you* who add the new items to `Destination`, so why do you ask the `TListView` to 'remind' you when the items are added? Indeed, you do it here:

```
Destination.Items.Add.Assign(source.Items[i]);
```

Here you add the `source.Items[i]` list item into `Destination` [strictly speaking, you create a new item in `Destination` and then 'assign' it the properties of `source.Items[i]`]. Anything you could do in `OnInsert`, you can just as well do here, and here you got full access to the list item in question: it's simply `source.Items[i]`. Do what you like with this data!

Comment: Thanks for the help, BTW I am using Delphi 7. howver when I try the above I can access the item.caption however I cannot access any of the item.subItems? It looks to me that they have not been assigned at this point? Colin

Comment: @colin: That's why I wrote "At least I wouldn't trust this hack.".

Comment: thanks for your help on this, I finally figured out another way to do it.